# How handle two or more async actions in one slice file in redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to **get** some data and **post** some data in **centerSlice.js** file on the backend using redux **createAsyncThunk** Now I have two async actions that I have to dispatch in order to perform the app logic, I have searched and tried my self a few ways but couldn't find the solution, So is there any other good way to do this logic.

Below is the code which I have tried but this doesn't work and it gives an error.

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import { postCenter, getCenters } from "../../../helpers/backend_helper";

const initialState = {
  data: [],
  centersAccess: null,
};

export const addCenter = createAsyncThunk(
  "postCenter",
  async (data, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const response = await toast.promise(postCenter(data), {
        pending: "Loading",
        success: "Successfull",
        error: "Failed",
      });

      return response;
    } catch (error) {
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue("something went wrong");
    }
  }
);

export const fetchCenters = createAsyncThunk(
  "getCenters",
  async (data, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const response = await toast.promise(getCenters(data), {
        pending: "Loading",
        success: "Successfull",
        error: "Failed",
      });

      return response;
    } catch (error) {
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue("something went wrong");
    }
  }
);

const centerSlice = createSlice({
  name: "center",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(postCenter.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(postCenter.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
        state.loading = false;
        state.data = [...state.data, payload];
      })
      .addCase(postCenter.rejected, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
      });

    builder
      .addCase(getCenters.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(getCenters.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
        state.loading = false;
        state.data = payload;
      })
      .addCase(getCenters.rejected, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
      });
  },
});

export const {} = centerSlice.actions;

export default centerSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: What's the error? What result did you expect?

Comment: sorry my bad I passed the wrong name of the action to extra reducers that's why it was giving this error sorry for the trouble, it was saying cannot read type of undefined. @LinDu

Comment: Can you edit your question and show the full error stack?